# Generate Drupal Calendar or Fullcallendar from arbitrary view

Tags: views, datetime, javascript

I have successfully used the [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) and [Fullcalendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) modules to generate calendars from a content type.

What I can't get to work is getting dates calculated using a [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) field into a calendar. The settings for Fullcalendar only appear to allow specification of a 'bone fide' Date field as the dates to display in the calendar.

I am sure this must be possible. I would be grateful for any pointers.